# Fourier transform with factor $(-1)$ rather than $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

My physics professor defined the following expression for the Fourier transforms of the current density in space and time:
$$
\Delta j_{i}(\mathbf{k}, \omega) \equiv \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^{2}} \iiiint e^{-i(\mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r}-\omega t)} \Delta j_{i}(\mathbf{r}, t) d^{3} r d t
$$
where it can be seen that each integral is scaled by a factor of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$. In the same calculations, he defined the following Fourier transform of the conductivity function:
$$
\widetilde{\sigma_{i j}}(\mathbf{k}, \omega) \equiv \iiiint \sigma_{i j}\left(\mathbf{r}^{\prime \prime}, t^{\prime \prime}\right) e^{-i\left(\mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r}^{\prime \prime}-\omega t^{\prime \prime}\right)}(-1)^{4} d^{3} r^{\prime \prime} d t^{\prime \prime}
$$
where it appears that each integral is scaled by $(-1)$. Can someone explain why the Fourier transforms might be defined differently?

Comment: The normalization of the Fourier transform and its inverse is a matter of convention. The only condition enforced is that the constant in front of the FT multiplied with the constant in front of the inverse FT gives $\frac{1}{(2\pi)^D}$ where $D=4$ in this case. But it would be weird to use different conventions for different integrals in the same text so I suspect this is not something we can answer (can for all we know just be a typo) so I would ask the person who actually wrote it.

Comment: Yes, what confuses me is that he uses two different definitions of the Fourier transform in the same derivation. The derivation leads to the expected result with these definitions, but the result differs by a factor of $(2\pi)^2$ if I do the same derivation with the Fourier transform of $\widetilde{\sigma_{i j}}(\mathbf{k}, \omega)$ defined the same way as the Fourier transform of $\Delta j_{i}(\mathbf{k}, \omega)$.